# nested if testing 3 cells in excel

Tags: excel

given the image below, I want to test for the highest AvgGain+ cells with a yes so I can determine the Difference in Actual exit vs max reached. I've tried a dozen variations of nested if's but im not coming up with the right result

[image: Sheet Headers]
My last attempt

```
=IF(I2="Yes",(D2+H2)-F2,IF(J2="Yes",(D2+(H2*1.1)-F2,IF(K3,D2+(H2*1.2)-F2,D2+(H2*1.1)-F2))))
```

but its coming up with .37c when it should be calculating from the cell K2 Yes value and returning 71c.

Comment: Is AvgGain+20 the "highest AvgGain+ cell"? Then shouldn't you test K2 first instead of I2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is : your test is stopping at the first if 
that means that it is always taking I columns 
because if J is true then I is (I is avg and J is 1.1 avg)
        if K is true then I is (I is avg and K is 1.2 avg)

you should test K columns first then J, then I

the correct formula would be :

```
IF(K2="Yes",(D2+H2*1.2)-F2,IF(J2="Yes",(D2+(H2*1.1)-F2,IF(I2="Yes",D2+ H2-F2, "Avg Gain Not Reached"))))
```

Comment: =IF(K2="Yes",(D2+H2*1.2)-F2,IF(J2="Yes",(D2+(H2*1.1)-F2,IF(I2="Yes",D2+ H2-F2, "Avg Gain Not Reached")))) ...is the correct formula